# How to configure AUCTeX in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, emacs, environment-variables, latex, auctex

Help me, please! This is my 3rd attempt at a clean install of EMACS/AUCTeX **in Windows 7**.

I'm following [Joachim Schlosser's installation guide](http://www.latexbuch.de/install-latex-windows-7/#x1-150003.4) to AUCTeX but I'm getting confused at least on 2 points.

1. If I want to extract EMACS' archive in `C:/Program Files/Emacs/`, what should the HOME environment variable look like? Mr. Schlosser puts a lot of emphasis on erasing spaces in the path-file but the other User environment variables all have spaces in their path-file so maybe it is irrelevant? These are mine, at present:

   **HOME** → `C:\ProgramFiles\Emacs\` and

   **PATH** → `C:\ProgramFiles\Aspell\bin\;C:\ProgramFiles\gs\gs9.09\bin\;C:\ProgramFiles\SumatraPDF\;`
2. Where exactly do I extract the AUCTeX files? Which files are to be moved in EMACS' folders and which should I leave outside? A snapshot of Windows' EMACS folder would really help me here.

Comment: How about `M-x list-packages` and just install AUCTeX by clicking on that package?

Comment: Is the command you suggested, suited for Win7? (Sorry for the dumb question, I'm still learning emacs).

Comment: These days I install to `c:\emacs` rather than to program files. Less worrying about spaces for a start. That aside, it's not clear to me what problem you have. Is Emacs not working? Or AucTeX? Or both? What kind of error is being generated? Suggest you edit your question above to include this information - do not include the information in the comments here.

Answer (score 0):

I decided for a clean install, afterall.

As stated in the question, I followed Joachim Schlosser's guide ([website guide in english](http://www.latexbuch.de/install-latex-windows-7/#x1-150003.4) + [youtube tutorial in german](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFal48NzVBo)).

I would suggest to anyone trying to install and configure AUCTeX, to first read the guide then download all the necessary binaries and zip files in one folder and imitate what the tutorial does (I don't speak German but I still pulled it off).

I had a couple of doubts regarding where to put the `emacs-24.2` folder, whether in `C:/` or in `C:/Program Files/`; I opted for the latter. Next, when you have to download the LibPNG binaries, it's better to download the all-in-one *.zip bundle of GTK+ from the link in Schlosser's website; open the zip bundle, go to the `/bin` folder and select only the `*.dll` files that Schlosser shows (just update the version number accordingly).

If you do what he does, things should work out fine. This solved 80-85% of my problems.

I'm still having problems...

1. setting SumatraPDF as default viewer for EMACS *only* (Acrobat
   Reader will be the system's default)
2. doing forward/inverse search (this feature works for SumatraPDF but not Acrobat
   Reader)
3. previewing math expressions within the *.tex file

I'll see if anyone had similar problems here in SX or I'll post my own question. Anyways, I hope this helps others too.